# Equation of plane that contain the given vector equation

Tags: vectors

> Equation of the plane that contains the curve with the given vector equation $r(t)=<6t,2\sin(t),2t+12>$

What i try :: Campare $r(t)=<x,y,z>$, We get

$x=6t,y=\sin(t),z=2t+12$

Now eliminating $t$ from $x,z$, We get

$3z=6t+36=x+36\Longrightarrow x-3z+36=0$

But i did not understand what is the use of $y=3\sin(t)$ Here

Please explain me. Also explain me what should be the equation of plane. Thanks

Comment: You think that all the points represented by that vector equation are coplanar? That's an interesting question in itself...

Comment: Your parametric curve $\vec{r}(t)$ can be thought of as the intersection $$\{x-3z+36=0\} \cap\{y=2\sin(x/6)\}\cap \mathbb{R}^3$$ which is contained in the plane you mention.